# JavaFx application in Windows is not displaying text correctly

Tags: java, windows, javafx

So I have an application written in JavaFx 2.2 that has been packaged for linux, mac, and windows. I am getting a strange issue with some of the text fields though. The application will read a file and populate some labels based on whats found in the file. When run on ubuntu or mac we get a result like [image] as you can see we have that special accent character over the c and it looks just fine. However in Windows it shows up like this [image]. Any idea as to why this is happening? I was a bit confused as it is the same exact application on all three. Thanks.

Comment: This is likely a problem with character encoding. What encoding is used in the file? What is the code that reads that file? My guess is that the file is read using the platform default encoding (which might be e.g. Windows 1252 or Windows 1250 or ISO-8859-1 or ISO-8859-2 or something), but the file is actually in a different encoding, e.g. UTF-8.

Comment: If I diagnosed the problem correctly, the solution is to specify the correct encoding when reading the file.

Comment: Thanks I will look into this and let you know how it goes

Comment: This seems to have fixed it, Thanks! If you could answer this as an answer so I can mark it as answered that would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure to specify character encoding when reading the file, in order to avoid using the platform's default encoding, which varies between operating systems. Just by coincidence, the default on Linux and Mac happens to match the file encoding and produces correct output, but you should not rely on it.